# Monsters respawn and loot in Legend of Grimrock

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I have two simple questions about monsters in Legend of Grimrock.

- Do monsters respawn?

This is important to me to understand if I can safely rest or looking around the level, once I have defeated all monsters a dungeon floor or section.

- Is Monsters' loot fixed or random?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Mosters loot is fix or random?

Monster's loot is fixed, in that they will always only drop certain types of items, and there aren't any "rare drops".  But they don't always drop common items, either.  For example, a snail won't always drop a snail slice.

It is also fixed in that some monsters drop special items.  But this is pre-scripted (part of puzzles/challenges), and you aren't going to repeatedly be able to kill a monster that will drop the special item.

> Do monsters respawn?

Not unless you're moving.

I've mapped out at least a few static triggers where if you walk over the specific spot on the floor a monster will spawn.  But if you don't walk over that tile, and you've cleared it out, the room is perfectly safe to sleep in.

In fact you can even sleep on the trigger.  It waits for you to walk onto it to fire, rather than simply detecting your presence.  They won't spawn a monster every time you walk over the tile, though, because they have a cooldown before they reset.

> This is important to me to understand if I can safely rest

Sometimes it is hard to tell if there are still enemies, as they don't all immediately home in on your location.  Also, some monsters are harder to detect than others.  You'll get a sense for this as the game progresses and you get more familiar with each monster.

There are often safe rooms you can lock yourself in, as monsters generally can't open doors.

Comment: *Generally* can't open doors?? :/

Comment: Goromorg (the hooded casters) can open doors, I learned to my surprise

Answer (score 8):

I haven't completed the game yet (level 8 or so), the following is what I had found so far:

1. Monster loot is fixed (snails drop snail slices, skeleton warrios drop a shield and lance) and I haven't seen any other random stuff drop from monsters like weapons and armor
2. Monsters do generally **not** respawn, unless:

   - In some regions, some "food providing" monsters did respawn after some time. I remember on level 6, I think, there is a large room with about 10 or more snails which drop food. These respawned after some time.
   - Some regions require monsters in order to solve a riddle to continue the game. These will spawn indefinitely (although I only killed them like 3-4 times in a row until I realized I need to do *other* stuff with them). ;) But they won't drop special items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Snakes?  Or snails?

Comment: Of course it's snails. Edited my answer ;)